# Execute Long Stored Procedure via Web page

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, struts, long-integer

I have this web application (using Struts 1.x) running on Weblogic 10.3.3 that read files and input the data to a database (Oracle 11g DB). And also through this web application, I can run a stored procedure in the database. The problem is now after a few changes on the stored procedure, it requires a pretty long time to finish executing (25-40 minutes).

The page to run the stored procedure now will load, and even after the stored procedure has finished (checked through session browser), the page will still in loading state and after sometimes it will display timeout error.

Is there any way for a web page to run a stored procedure that takes long time to finish (60 minutes)? Should I make changes to the application code or the Weblogic setting?

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never ever ever ever leave the user waiting. When I last dealt with that:

1. Client(user/browser) tells server "Start procedure"
2. Server spawns thread which starts the procedure.
3. Server tells Client(user/browser) "I is done now. come back later. Mabee I emails yoo"
4. Server completes procedure.
5. Server emails user that procedure is done.
6. Secondary thread terminates.
7. Server eats Sir Robin's minstrels and there is much rejoicing.

Comment: Well, maybe the server never ate Sir Robin's minstrels, but I pretended that they did.

Comment: The simple way, in Oracle, to run a procedure asynchronously is to use DBMS_JOB or DBMS_SCHEDULER.